# Text not always appearing when hovering over it

Tags: html, css, text, hover, mousehover

On my homepage there are 5 logos with text appearing when hovered over. 
However sometimes the text does not appear.

Sometimes (rarely), only the red background appears. There must be a problem with my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container1">

    <div class="backgrounds">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
    </div>

<a href="..."> 
    <div class="column" >

<div class="hover-lune1">
<img class="aligncenter" src="..."/>
</div>

<div class="hover-lune2">
<h2>LUNE</h2>
<p style="padding:0 10px 20px 10px; text-align:center">Quel instrument faut-il choisir pour observer la Lune ?</p>
</div>

    </div>
</a>


<a href="..."> 
same structure
</a>


<a href="...">
same structure
</a>


<a href="...">
same structure
</a>


<a href="...">
same structure
</a>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hover-lune1:hover {
background:#dd0000;
}
.hover-lune1 {
width:43px;
margin-left:59px
}
.hover-lune2 {
display:none;
}
.hover-lune1:hover + .hover-lune2 {
display:block;
width:200px;
position:relative;
top:-13px;
left:-20px;
z-index:-2;
text-align: center;
}

>> same for the other logos



.column { 
position:relative; 
float:left; 
width:18%; 
margin:0 1%; 
}
```

My website: http://www.chooseyourtelescope.com/fr/

Comment: Yes the names are totally confusing ;). As I say the "not appearing problem" is rare: for example it happened only 2 times today while I worked on it for hours.

Comment: BTW I don't see extra </div> or <p> ...

Comment: Nope you are right did not look good. Will delete my comment, but it also happened to me while I was watching the website and I started to open the console and see what happened. It looks like the event (hover) still triggers the CSS hover state but it does not appear, weird right!?

Comment: Yeah thats weird. Maybe a problem with the browser or something which has nothing to do with CSS? Are you on Chrome?

Comment: Yes I am on Chrome, very strange indeed...

Comment: I am on Chrome too. Maybe a problem with that... I don't know

Comment: I got 59 errors when running your page through a HTML validator. Might want to work on fixing that first.

Comment: I fixed most of the errors (the tool found some errors that don't exist) but the problem is still there...